# Responsive menu does not show

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, responsive

I have created a responsive menu but it doesn't show. I would like to use a `hamburger menu` button. When it is active (**button transform+transition**, the **hamburger menu icon** -> the `close icon`), the `ul` will slide out from the right ( **background** -> `opacity.5`).

I am not sure which part is erroneous. Do you have any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
}

.button-container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: .6;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}

li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  width: 30%;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?">Stargazing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it run as [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `visibility:visible` to `.active` class. and also some  css modification to show menu bars.

```
.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.button-container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: none;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.middle{
  top:10px;
}
.bottom{
  top:20px;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: .6;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}

li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  width: 30%;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?">Stargazing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The menu button shows now, but it is not active (button transform and full-screen menu).

Comment: I guess this code may wrong, but not sure. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you so much. 


CSS:
.button-container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

Answer (score 0):

I would make a second class for the mobile devices.

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay"> // copy //Change Class
  <nav class="overlay-menu"> //copy //Change Class
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?">Stargazing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```